# Index out of range in MasterMind game

Tags: python

```
def MasterMind():

    import random
    tries = 10
    numbers_correct = 0
    password = random.randint(1,5),random.randint(1,5),random.randint(1,5),random.randint(1,5), random.randint(1,5)
    while(not numbers_correct == 5 and tries > 0):
        guess = input("To access the treasure you have to guess the password!!! Guess the 5 digit password between numbers 1-5 ")
        guess=guess.split()
        numbers_correct = 0
        tries = tries - 1
        for i in range(len(password)):
            if (str(password[i]) == guess[i]):
                numbers_correct = numbers_correct + 1
    print(str(numbers_correct) + " out of 5 correct")
    print("you have " + str(tries) + " tries left")
    if numbers_correct == 5:
        print ("Congrats, you've gained access to the treasure!!!")
    else:
        print("sorry, you couldn't get to the treasure. The correct password was " + (password))


MasterMind()
```

I think the problem is with line 11 though im not sure.

I'm trying to explain how to use python in my univerisity tutorial class but i keep getting an error that says:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/mastermind.py", line 25, in <module>
    MasterMind()
  File "C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/mastermind.py", line 15, in MasterMind
    if (str(password[i]) == guess[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Kinda in a pickle, i need a new set of eyes to try to find the problem

Comment: The exception tells you where the error is, so you don't have to guess. And if you paste the exception ere instead of just describing it, it also tells _us_ where the error is, so we can help you a lot more easily.

Comment: @abarnert I added the error

Comment: Meanwhile, if line 11 is the one that says `if (str(password[i]) == guess[i]):`, that could well be the problem. `guess` is as long as however many separate words the user types at the input. So if you type `1 2 3 4 5` it should be OK, but if you type `1 2 3 4`, or `12345`, it will raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: guess.split() is not working the way you envisioned it to be.

Comment: If you actually _want_ users to enter `54123` without spaces, you don't want the `split`—`guess[0]` will be `'5'`, then `guess[1]` will be `4`, and so on. (You might still want some nicer error handling than exiting the program with an `IndexError` if they typo `5412`, but at least it would only be a problem on bad input, not on good input.)

Comment: @abarnert ill try that thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
guess = input("To access the treasure you have to guess the password!!! Guess the 5 digit password between numbers 1-5 ")
guess=guess.split()
```

… that `split()` turns `guess` into a list of words, separated by spaces.

So, if the user types `1 5 3 4 2`, that's five words—you will get the list `['1', '5', '3', '4', '2']`. And then your code doesn't raise an exception.

But if the user types `15342`, without spaces, that's just one word, and you will get the list `['15342']`. So then, when you try to access `guess[1]` in the loop, that's past the end of the list, so you get an `IndexError`.

If you didn't want the user to type spaces, just remove this line:

```
guess=guess.split()
```

You can, of course, try to make it smarter so it can accept *both* kinds of input:

```
guess = [ch for ch in guess if ch.isdigit()]
```

But of course you'll still get the error if the user typos and gives you `1523` instead of `15234`.

You can use `try` and `except` to get some nicer error handling for that case instead of an `IndexError` killing your program, but that may be beyond what you've learned so far.